# Вывод строки из SQLite в TextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть есть база данных с двумя строками. Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую в TextView выводятся все данные из столбцов базы данных. Как можно вывести в этот TextView только одну строку?

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);

    mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // Задайте значения для каждого столбца
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.NAME_COLUMN, "ПЕТР");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.PHONE_COLUMN, "495455321213");
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.AGE_COLUMN, "7");
    // Вставляем данные в таблицу
     // mSqLiteDatabase.insert("students", null, values);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("students", new String[]{DatabaseHelper.NAME_COLUMN,
                    DatabaseHelper.PHONE_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.AGE_COLUMN},
            null, null,
            null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int phone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PHONE_COLUMN));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NAME_COLUMN));
        TextView infoTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        infoTextView2.append(" "  +cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));

    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

**DatabaseHelper:**

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

// названия столбцов
public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
public static final String PHONE_COLUMN = "phone";
public static final String AGE_COLUMN = "age";
// имя базы данных
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
// версия базы данных
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// имя таблицы
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "students";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME_COLUMN
        + " text not null, " + PHONE_COLUMN + " integer, " + AGE_COLUMN
        + " integer);";

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                      int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                      int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Запишем в журнал
    Log.w("SQLite", "Обновляемся с версии " + oldVersion + " на версию " + newVersion);

    // Удаляем старую таблицу и создаём новую
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    // Создаём новую таблицу
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

убрать цикл, или сразу сделать запрос на получение только одной строки.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("students", new String[]{DatabaseHelper.NAME_COLUMN,
                    DatabaseHelper.PHONE_COLUMN, DatabaseHelper.AGE_COLUMN},
            null, null,
            null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToNext();
        int phone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PHONE_COLUMN));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NAME_COLUMN));
        TextView infoTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        infoTextView2.append(" "  +cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1));


    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Я получил первую строку. А как быть если мне надо получить именно вторую строку ?

Comment: выполните  cursor.moveToNext(); дважды - это будет вторая строка. Или сделать правильный запрос.

Comment: а в запросе их количество сократить не получается? Зачем искать все строки из бд, если нужна только 496? Значит она чем особенная, и эту особенность нужно указать в запросе и извлечь одну строку, а не 500.

Comment: Можете показать в вашем ответе как это можно реализовать? @ValeraKvip

Comment: Я не знаю  какая у тебя бд, и в чем особенность 496 строки.

Comment: На примере двух строк, которые есть. @ValeraKvip

Comment: Нет, я все равно не знаю по какому критерию ты хочешь найти строку.